# Groovy - groovy-datetime module

Tags: apache, datetime, groovy, module

So I am trying to learn groovy, but I am experiencing some issues with datetime module.
I was looking for answer for 2 hours but I found only one "advice" that haven't helped me.

When I run `groovysh` in console I get warnings about module that was unable to load:

```
V 31, 2018 10:10:35 DOP. org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule
 newModule

WARNING: Module [groovy-datetime] - Unable to load extension class [org.apache.g
roovy.datetime.extensions.DateTimeExtensions]
V 31, 2018 10:10:35 DOP. org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule
 newModule

WARNING: Module [groovy-datetime] - Unable to load extension class [org.apache.g
roovy.datetime.extensions.DateTimeStaticExtensions]
```

It is groovy 2.5.0, can anybody help me? It also appears with every run of scripts, it's extremely annoying.

Comment: See [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/groovy-dev/201805.mbox/%3CCAMbkE7QR1ypi07MmxBOo5bzAriSSzncV2CyTCA294LBP8LknuQ@mail.gmail.com%3E). TL;DR: use Java 8 instead of Java 7

Comment: I missed that when i read it, thank you, worked